# Custom delegate for NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, macos, inheritance, delegates

I want to create a custom delegate for `NSWindow`.
CustomWindow is subclassed to get notified about `NSWindowDelegate` events.
Now I want to create `delegate` for this `CustomWindow`.

I tried following code:

CustomWindow.h

```
@class CustomWindow;

@protocol CustomWindowDelegate

- (void)method1:(CustomWindow *)sender userInfo:(NSMutableDictionary*) userInfo;
- (void)method2:(CustomWindow *)sender event:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)method3:(CustomWindow *)sender;

@end

@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) id <CustomWindowDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

mainDocument.h

```
#import "CustomWindow.h"

@interface mainDocument : NSDocument

@property (assign) IBOutlet CustomWindow *mainWindow;

@end
```

mainDocument.m

```
#import "mainDocument.h"

@implementation mainDocument

- (void)method1:(CustomWindow *)sender userInfo:(NSMutableDictionary*) userInfo
{
...
...
}

- (void)method2:(CustomWindow *)sender event:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
...
...
}

- (void)method3:(CustomWindow *)sender
{
...
...
}

@end
```

Its working as per expectations however its giving following warnings:

> 'retain (or strong)' attribute on property 'delegate' does not match the property inherited from 'NSWindow'
>
> 'atomic' attribute on property 'delegate' does not match the property inherited from 'NSWindow'
>
> Property type 'id' is incompatible with type 'id _Nullable' inherited from 'NSWindow'
>
> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'delegate'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention

How can I get rid of these warnings ?

Any helps are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSWindow` already has a `delegate` property and it uses its delegate for different purposes than you're using yours for. The errors are conflicts between your declaration of your `delegate` property with the declaration of the inherited property.

The simplest solution is for you to rename your property to `customDelegate` or something like that. Also, the general convention is for delegate properties to be `weak`, so you should probably declare yours as `weak`, too.

In general, one could combine a new delegate protocol with `NSWindowDelegate` and re-use the existing `delegate` property. In your case, though, since you've declared `CustomWindow` to conform to `NSWindowDelegate`, it seems like you're planning on making the window object its own delegate. So, that would conflict with this approach. But, for completeness, if you were going to do that you'd declare your protocol as an extension of `NSWindowDelegate`:

```
@protocol CustomWindowDelegate <NSWindowDelegate>
```

Your property declaration would have to have the same attributes as `NSWindow`'s declaration of its `delegate` property. So:

```
@property (nullable, assign) id<CustomWindowDelegate> delegate;
```

Finally, since you're relying on `NSWindow` to actually provide the storage and accessor methods of the property, you'd fix the last warning by putting this in the `@implementation` of `CustomWindow`:

```
@dynamic delegate;
```

Comment: Thanks. The second option of '_one could combine a new delegate protocol with `NSWindowDelegate` and re-use the existing delegate property_' worked for me