# Why is NSWindow delegate being overwritten?

Tags: swift, cocoa, delegates

I am trying to use NSWindowDelegate *windowWillClose* by setting the delegate in the following function. It is set up in the Interface Builder without an delegate link (i tried setting it but it won't connect).
The View Controller is contained in another window controller.
This ViewController class implements NSWindowDelegate and sets the delegate following way:

**func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) :**

```
if segue.identifier=="My Segue"
{
    let v=segue.destinationController as! CenterWindowController
    chatWindowController=v
    v.window!.delegate=self
}
```

The problem is something is overwriting the delegate after the prepareForSegue.

CenterWindowController (NSWindowController) is the **incorrect** delegate !

I found this out by overriding the didSet property on NSWindow:

```
class MyWindow :NSWindow
{
    override var delegate: NSWindowDelegate? {
        willSet {
            Swift.print("WillSet aVar to \(newValue) from \(delegate)")
        }
        didSet { // this is my temporary solution , reversing the incorrect overwrite
            if let d=delegate as? CenterWindowController {
                delegate=oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem doesn't happen if i instantiate the window controller by myself:

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)

if let vc = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Transport Detail") as? CenterWindowController,let f=view.window?.frame
{
    let tdc=vc.contentViewController as!  TransportDetailController
    tdc.transportController=self
    vc.window?.delegate=self

    vc.setCenterPos(f)
    vc.showWindow(vc)

    transportDetailWindowController=vc
}
```

**How can i disable the automatic overwrite of the NSWindow delegate ?
Should i implement another way of notyfing the close event? Can it be caused by some setting in the Interface Builder?**

After i implemented the fix in **didSet** the problem went away and my delegate windowWillClose is called correctly.

possibly relevant : [Custom delegate for NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383069/custom-delegate-for-nswindow)

Comment: Usually the window controller is the delegate of the window. Do you really need the view controller to be the delegate or is observing a notification an option?

Comment: Did you check if the delegate of the window is connected to the window controller in Interface Builder?

Comment: Willeke: yes i did check, i tried connecting it again, and it can't be.

Comment: I want the view controller to be the delegate because it is the shortest path. I could route it through the window controller, but that is an unneccesary step from my point of view. Anyway , your answer shed light to why this happens, so it answered my question. If you want , write an answer and i will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Implementing `windowWillClose` will automatically add the delegate as a observer of the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification. You can also add the the view controller as observer of the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification. The window controller is not involved. Will this solve your problem?

Comment: I forgot to add, the View Controller is in a different window. Maybe that is the reason it didn't work. I implemented `windowWillClose` as my first try. Maybe that is the reason the `windowWillClose` didn't get added as a observer.